# VB6 not desired result reading c:\test.txt

Tags: vb6

I start out with text103.text having a text value of what I want to check C:\test.txt for.  So if whatever's in text103.text matches up with whatever's in C:\test.txt label3.caption should read "success" yet every time I run it, I get "failure"  why??

So here's the code in my button:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    nFileNum = FreeFile
    Open "C:\test.txt" For Input As nFileNum
    lLineCount = 1

    Do While Not EOF(nFileNum)
       Line Input #nFileNum, sNextLine
       sNextLine = sNextLine & vbCrLf
       sText = sText & sNextLine
    Loop
    Text102.Text = sText
    Close nFileNum


    If Text102.Text = Text103.Text Then
        Label3.Caption = "success"
    Else
        Label3.Caption = "failure"
    End If


End Sub
```

Even when my text103.text starts out as "hello" and I edit the C:\test.txt to just say "hello" it always gives me label3.caption "failure"!!! Why???

Comment: Please reformat your question so source code is source code. That's easier on the eye. Thank you!

Comment: why dont you break on the if statement and check the contents of Text102.Text and Text103.Text?  you may need to trim some of Text102.Text

Comment: I don't get it, Im a very new programmer, but when I look at the textboxes 102 and 103, I see they contain the same word.

Comment: I agree with the answers so far, it's the newline you add to the end of sNextLine. `hello` and `hello\r\n` are not equal, even though they may look the same to you in the debugger, because the newline characters are not displayed.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly because you are always adding a newline to the data read from the file.
Does `Text103.Text` contain a new line too?

**Update:**

`vbCrLf` aka `\r\n` are part of the set of **whitespace characters** so you may not be able to see them directly.

Before `If Text102.Text = Text103.Text Then` try
`msgbox "Len 102 " & Len(Text102.Text) & " Len 103 " & Len(Text103.Text)`
this will show that the strings are different lengths, therefore they cannot be equal.

Alternatively, in immediate mode try `? "[" & text102.Text & "]"` and `? "[" & text103.Text & "]"` Assuming the word in question is "Hello", I'll bet the first will print

[Hello
]

and the second
[Hello]

Comment: Both text102.text and text103.text should only contain one line (a word).

Comment: Lets assume the text file contains `Hello`. In the loop you add a `vbCrlF` to it, so `Text102.Text` now contains `Hello` **plus two extra characters**, which are a carrige return and line feed (i.e. vbCrLf)

Comment: Yeah, but you are appending the vbCrLf to sNextLine.  That means that sText includes one vbCrLf.  Text103.txt doesn't appear to.  Thus, they will never match.  Perhaps you should show us where Text103.txt gets its value from.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are adding newline characters text103.text does not have this.

Comment: Text103 is only one line and should always be only one line... Do I just remove 

Line Input #nFileNum, sNextLine

?

Comment: It may be one line but you are adding a newline character anyway:

sNextLine = sNextLine & vbCrLf
sText = sText & sNextLine

So your text file may read: "hello", but sText will read "hello\n".

Answer (score 2):

Could it be to do with your trailing carriage return? It looks like your file read will always have a vbCrLf on the end of it whereas possibly your text103 doesn't. Can you go into debug mode and confirm exactly what each string contains?

Comment: It doesn't give me any debugging errors.. it runs smooth, but the label caption always says failure.

Comment: Thank you, the vbCrLf seemed to be the culprit

Answer (score 2):

I'd make a guess that it's to do with the newlines (`vbCrLf`) that you add, or some similar character.

Otherwise it might be case dependant, you could try adding `Option Compare Text` at the top of the file.

Comment: Yes thank you, I simply removed "+ vbCrLf" and got success. Thak you ho1!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

nFileNum = FreeFile
Open "C:\test.txt" For Input As nFileNum
lLineCount = 1

Do While Not EOF(nFileNum)
   Line Input #nFileNum, sNextLine
   sNextLine = sNextLine & vbCrLf
   sText = sText & sNextLine
Loop
Text102.Text = sText
Close nFileNum


If Replace$(Text102.Text, VBCrLf, "") = Replace$(Text103.Text, VbCrLf, "") Then
    Label3.Caption = "success"
Else
    Label3.Caption = "failure"
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: That would work but he shouldn't be adding new lines anyway, or reading the file like that :P